# "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation" when adding migration in WebApi

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-migrations

I am working on ASP.NET Web Api running on .net 4.8. I am trying to migrate some entities but I am getting this error below.

```
add-migration deleted_authtable
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Capstone2.Entities, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. Operation is not supported. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131515) ---> System.NotSupportedException: An attempt was made to load an assembly from a network location which would have caused the assembly to be sandboxed in previous versions of the .NET Framework. This release of the .NET Framework does not enable CAS policy by default, so this load may be dangerous. If this load is not intended to sandbox the assembly, please enable the loadFromRemoteSources switch. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=155569 for more information.

   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(AssemblyName assemblyRef)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Design.Executor..ctor(String assemblyFile, IDictionary`2 anonymousArguments)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(String assemblyString, String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, Evidence securityInfo, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(String assemblyName, String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)
   at System.AppDomain.CreateInstance(String assemblyName, String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)
   at System.AppDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(String assemblyName, String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)
   at System.AppDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(String assemblyName, String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)
   at System.Data.Entity.Tools.AppDomainExecutor..ctor(String assembly, String dataDirectory, String configurationFile, String rootNamespace, String language)
   at System.Data.Entity.Tools.Commands.ProjectCommandBase.CreateExecutor()
   at System.Data.Entity.Tools.Commands.MigrationsAddCommand.Execute()
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.CommandLine.CommandLineApplication.Execute(String[] args)
   at System.Data.Entity.Tools.Program.Main(String[] args)
Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
```

[image]

Here is an image of what my Entity looks like. I am not  able to understand where the migration is going wrong.

Everything was working fine until I deleted an Entity i.e "Auth_*Table" from the Entity folder and I am not able to figure out how too solve this. I also manually deleted the Auth*_Table from the database thinking it my solve the problem but it did not help. Any help will be highly appreciated. Please excuse me if this is a very naive question.

Comment: Try to delete obj and bin folders

Comment: Hey @Lonli-Lokli, Thanks but the problem still exists : (

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add [loadFromRemoteSources tag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/dd409252(v=vs.100)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) in the configuration file:

```
<configuration>
   <runtime>
      <loadFromRemoteSources enabled="true"/>
   </runtime>
</configuration>
```

If this doesn't work, you can try some steps below:

1. Clean your project. Rebuild.
2. Upgrade your EntityFramework via Nuget (Package Manager Console).
3. Update your model from database.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hey, I tried all those steps but it still dosnt work. Anyways, thank : )